# What are the exact HTTP requests to follow in order to log in to gmail without using any client libraries/solutions like SMTP

Tags: rest, http, google-api, google-oauth, gmail-api

I want to log in to gmail using its REST API without using any client libraries. So, there should be only HTTP/HTTPS requests and maybe a handshake + key calculation (basically what a browser does).

I tried searching for the gmail API as well as logging through the browser and observing the network tab. Neither worked fully.

Comment: "Neither worked fully" is not a problem description.

Comment: Could not find gmail rest api documentation so that’s why that option didn’t work. 

As of following the browser based requests, too many requests are made and it was difficult to follow.

Comment: The documentation for authorization can be hard to find i have linked that in my answer below.   The rest calls for gmail can be found in their docs under each method. I have fixed your tags a little you were tagging it in a few vague tags this can make people misunderstand your question.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to log in to gmail using its REST API without using any client libraries.

There are a few things you may be misunderstanding.  First the term Login implies that you want to use your login and pass word for the gmail account.  This was called client login and was disabled by Google around may 2015.

The term you may need be missunderstanding is the term login or sign-in. One does not login to an api to use it.  One requests consent of the user to access their data.

In order to access gmail data using the rest api you need to use Oauth2 and no you do not need to use the client libraries the calls are all https and can be done without the libraries.

Assuming this is a web app try and check [web-server#httprest](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#httprest) with desktop app the only real difference is the loop back address is http://127.0.0.1

Once you have an access token the requests you need to make for gmail can all be found in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/list) you just send the access token as a bearer token authorization header.

```
GET https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/{userId}/messages
Authorization: Bearer [access token]
```

I have done it before for a client. Its a nice learning exercise not depending upon a library and building it yourself from the ground up.

Comment: Hi, 

Thank you for your comments and I agree that the way I presented my problem is wrong. 

My real requirement is this. I want to establish a secure connection with Gmail before sharing the actual tokens or credentials. This is because, in my requirement, I cannot "trust" the entity that initiates the request. So I want to do a handshake (sharing of public keys) first and then proceed with the rest of the signing-in process. 

I do not know whether Gmail supports such APIs.

Comment: it does not support that if you want to do some kind of pre authorization you will need to do that yourself.   If you dont trust them i suspect you will have a very hard tie getting this app past the verification certification stage with google they wont trust them either.

Comment: Thanks. Please find my better-described problem in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/78187382/17745082).

I just need to be able to send an email through the terminal. In such a case that Gmail does not support such APIs, do you think I would be able to do it for any other social media (Twitter, Facebook etc)

Comment: I have managed a way to do a TLS handshake with the Gmail server. The normal login through oauth does not work as the end point in https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#httprest_2 returns a HTML page to enter credentials (which I do not want). 

I figured service accounts are the way to go but still searching for the exact REST endpoints to hit in order to sign in

Comment: @linda-lawton-daimto The success response to [web-server#httprest](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#httprest) is a HTML page where we have to enter credentials. Is it possible to do it a separate way as I can only afford to do access REST API through terminal (not browser).

Comment: The oauth2 consent screen must be displayed in the browser

Comment: Oh okay. Unfortunately, that makes it unusable for my use case. That means I will have to find some other approach. Thanks.

Comment: I have a consulting you can find my contact in my profile.   I have been using this system for more then ten years if anyone can help you find a workaround its me., but i need more info on your usecase